# Attempted to call an undefined method named "getPosition" of class "App\Controller\ApiController"

Tags: php, sql, symfony

I am trying to instantiate a domain object in my controller but I am getting this error "Attempted to call function "getPosition" from namespace "App\Controller"".

I hope you can help me, whit that problem.
[This is me error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha6B9.png)

But i have get and set then why he don't find it?

**ApiController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Domain;
use App\Repository\DomainRepository;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\AbstractFOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/api")
 */
class ApiController extends AbstractFOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Rest\Get("/domain", name="get_domain")
     * @Rest\Get("/domain/{blocked}")
     *
     * @throws
     */
    public function getDomain(Request $request, Reader $reader, DomainRepository $domainRepository, MailerInterface $mailer): JsonResponse
    {
        $record = $reader->country('87.99.79.119');
        $code   = $record->country->isoCode;
        $domain = $domainRepository->getDomain($code);
        $ip     = $request->getClientIp();
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $domain = $domainRepository->getDomain($code);
        }
        $position = getPosition();
        //
        //        $email = (new Email())
        //            ->from('noreply@makaobet.com')
        //            ->to('support@makaobet.com')
        ////            ->cc('cc@example.com')
        ////            ->bcc('bcc@example.com')
        ////            ->replyTo('fabien@example.com')
        ////            ->priority(Email::PRIORITY_HIGH)
        //            ->subject('Domain Error')
        //            ->html($domain->getDomain() . ' have problem!');
        //
        //        $mailer->send($email);

        return new JsonResponse(
            [
                'status' => 'ok',
                'domain' => $domain->getDomainName(),
            ], 200);
    }
}
```

**Domain Entity**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DomainRepository")
 */
class Domain
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $domain_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array")
     */
    private $blocked_countries;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\SortablePosition
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $position;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDomainName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->domain_name;
    }

    public function setDomainName(string $domain_name): self
    {
        $this->domain_name = $domain_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBlockedCountries(): ?array
    {
        return $this->blocked_countries;
    }

    public function setBlockedCountries(array $blocked_countries): self
    {
        $this->blocked_countries = $blocked_countries;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPosition(): ?int
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function setPosition($position): self
    {
        $this->position = $position;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

How can I make this work???

Comment: You are calling a function, not a method, looks like you are missing `$domain->`

Comment: @msg $domain->$position = getPosition() like that?

Comment: The other way around: `$position = $domain->getPosition();`

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this tow work, anything you call from repository shoulkd be like:

```
$domainRepository->getSomethig();
```

and same for setting:

```
$domainRepository->setSomething("some Value");
```

So in your case:

```
$position = $domainRepository->getPosition();
```